# Merge multiple SQL-files on-device Android using Java

Tags: java, android, sql

In my Android application I've created multiple .db files with each containing multiple tables.

Is there a way to copy all tables to one central file? Is this possible without having to write a for loop for each individual row, table and file? Aka is there a simple way of doing this?

As the data is stored on-device it's not possible to use any server-side mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ATTACH DATABASE` instruction in SQLite. Here is [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

When you attach the database, use something like this `INSERT INTO DestinationTable SELECT * FROM attachedDatabase.SourceTable`

```
fun migration(context: Context) {
    val destinationDb = DatabaseHelper2(context)
    val sourceDbPath = context.getDatabasePath("database1.sqlite")

    val writableDb = destinationDb.writableDatabase
    writableDb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '${sourceDbPath.absolutePath}' AS attached")
    writableDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO DestinationTable SELECT * FROM attached.SourceTable")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll experiment with your suggestion and come back to you if it worked!